# Rails N+1 query : monkeypatching ActiveRecord::Relation#as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

### Situation

I have a model `User`:

```
def User
  has_many :cars

  def cars_count
    cars.count
  end

  def as_json options = {}
    super options.merge(methods: [:cars_count])
  end
end
```

#### Problem

When I need to render to json a collection of users, I end up being exposed to the N+1 query problem. It is my understanding that including cars doesn't solve the problem for me.

#### Attempted Fix

What I would like to do is add a method to `User`:

```
def User
  ...
  def self.as_json options = {}
    cars_counts = Car.group(:user_id).count
    self.map do |user|
      user.define_singleton_method(:cars_count) do
        cars_counts[user.id]
      end
      user.as_json options
    end
  end
end
```

That way all cars counts would be queried in a single query.

### Remaining Issue

`ActiveRecord::Relation` already has a `as_json` method and therefore doesn't pick the class defined one. How can I make `ActiveRecord::Relation` use the `as_json` method from the class when it is defined? Is there a better way to do this?

### Edits

#### 1. Caching

I can cache my `cars_count` method:

```
def cars_count
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/cars_count") do
    cars.count
  end
end
```

This is nice once the cache is warm, but if a lot of users are updated at the same time, it can cause request timeouts because a lot of queries have to be updated in a single request.

#### 2. Dedicated method

Instead of calling my method `as_json`, I can call it `my_dedicated_as_json_method` and each time I need to render a collection of users, instead of

```
render json: users
```

write

```
render json: users.my_dedicated_as_json_method
```

However, I don't like this way of doing. I may forget to call this method somewhere, someone else might forget to call it, and I'm losing clarity of the code. Monkey patching seems a better route for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `counter_cache` for `cars_count`? It's a good fit for what you're wanting to do.

This [blog article](https://blog.heroku.com/solving-n-plus-one-queries) also offers up some other alternatives, e.g. if you want to manually build a hash.

If you really wanted to continue down the monkey patching route, then ensure that you are patching `ActiveRecord::Relation` rather than `User`, and override the *instance* method rather than creating a class method. Note that this will then affect *every* `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but you can use `@klass` to add a condition that only runs your logic for `User`

```
# Just an illustrative example - don't actually monkey patch this way
# use `ActiveSupport::Concern` instead and include the extension
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def as_json(options = nil)
    puts @klass
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

In your user model:

```
def get_cars_count
  self.cars.count
end
```

And in your controller:

```
User.all.as_json(method: :get_cars_count)
```

## Option 2

You can create a method which will get all the users and their car count. And then you can call the as_json method on that.

It would roughly look like:

```
#In Users Model:

def self.users_with_cars
  User.left_outer_joins(:cars).group(users: {:id, :name}).select('users.id, users.name, COUNT(cars.id) as cars_count')

  # OR may be something like this
  User.all(:joins => :cars, :select => "users.*, count(cars.id) as cars_count", :group => "users.id")

end
```

And in your controller you can call `as_json`:

```
User.users_with_cars.as_json
```

Comment: In my controller I want to be able to do `render json: car_brand.users` and `render json: User.updated_in_last_hour` and many more. Option 1 has the N+1 query problem, Option 2 implies that I have to call `users_with_cars` everytime, which is not DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in case someone else is interested.

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb
require 'core_extensions/active_record/relation/serialization'

ActiveRecord::Relation.include CoreExtensions::ActiveRecord::Relation::Serialization

# lib/core_extensions/active_record/relation/serialization.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module CoreExtensions
  module ActiveRecord
    module Relation
      module Serialization
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          old_as_json = instance_method(:as_json)

          define_method(:as_json) do |options = {}|
            if @klass.respond_to? :collection_as_json
              scoping do
                @klass.collection_as_json options
              end
            else
              old_as_json.bind(self).(options)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
def User
  ...
  def self.collection_as_json options = {}
    cars_counts = Car.group(:user_id).count
    self.map do |user|
      user.define_singleton_method(:cars_count) do
        cars_counts[user.id]
      end
      user.as_json options
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks @gwcodes for pointing me at `ActiveSupport::Concern`.